# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installation. Windows 7 not detected

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04LTS on my new Lenovo Y510P using Live USB method. 
I know this question has be answered and one of them even had a long answer which was eventually converted to community wiki I guess but all of those answers did not work for me. I have 
1) 1-2 GB of System 
2) 200 GB C: with Windows NTFS
3) 600 GB of Data NTFS
4) 200 GB of Unallocated space for Ubuntu

However, os-prober doesnt detect Windows 7 to give me an option of installing along side.It just gives me an option of wipe out every thing or try something else.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6512255/) my paste bin from Boot-Repair utility.
Can anyone help me with that?

UPDATE: Here is the screenshot of GParted Utility

[image: GParted Screenshot from Live USB]

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to make a separate partition for installing ubuntu.For that you have to install gparted on live usb.

  ```
   sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```
- Open gparted and create new ext4 partition from that unallocated space.
- Now run the ubuntu installer and select the something else option.
- Now select the created ext4 partition and install ubuntu to it.And also create a swap partition(size will be double the RAM size).

Comment: The unallocated partition is not showing up in GParted.I just checked.

Comment: It doesn't hurt your installed windows and make sure that you are installing ubuntu on a partition other than the windows partition.you can't able to create linux swap partition from the windows os.

Comment: Upload gparted screenshot.

Comment: I updated the question with the screenshot. I can use EaseUSE or other tools to create the Linux partitions, cant I?

Comment: Screenshot shows there was nothing in your harddisk.

Comment: I am actually working/typing this comment from windows 7 right now.Thats the problem that I am facing.No partitions are seen by Ubuntu os-prober.

Comment: Did you installed windows 7 in the same pc?

Comment: Yes windows 7 is installed on the same pc.

Comment: what are the disks shown on clicking the top-right corner of gparted?